# Estimating number of attempts to reach a target sum with decreasing probability and effectiveness of each attempt

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've been struggling with this for a few weeks, as my math skills are poor these days. Hopefully someone can explain the answer to this in a basic way..

Essentially I have a number $x$ that needs to be increased to a target value $t$. Doing so has a probability to succeed. Each attempt to increase $x$ decreases the chance of success AND the amount by which $x$ would increase on the next attempt. I want to estimate how many attempts need to be made to reach the target.

If $n$ is the number of attempts, $x$ is the number, and $t$ is the target value of $x$, the increase on a success is
$$x_{n} = \lfloor\max \left((t-x_{n-1})(\frac {C_1}{n}+C_2),1\right)+0.5\rfloor +x_{n-1}$$
and the chance an attempt will succeed $s_n$ is
$$s_n = 1-(0.03+0.02n)+C_3$$
On a failure, there is also a 5% chance that $x$ will decrease by 1. $n$ increases on every attempt, success or no.

The constants $C_1, C_2, C_3$ are typically 0.5, 0.0 and 0.0 respectively, but could change. Typical value for $t$ is 10 or 15.

In English, the first attempt has a 95% chance to succeed, and will increase $x$ by 50% of the difference between it and $t$, rounded to the nearest integer. Each subsequent attempt is 2% less likely to succeed, and only increases by $\frac{50}n$% of the difference. Normally this would mean that you'd never reach the target, but a successful attempt has a minimum increase of 1.

What I've been doing up to now is "simulating" it by iterating through values of $n$, trying to calculate expected values, summing them on each iteration, and returning the total loops when the sum reaches the target. But I've come to realize my approach was really flawed and needs to be tossed out.

Is there a math wiz way to do this?